# Export table to exisiting sharepoint list from excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, datasheet, large-lists

Is it possible to export data from excel to exisiting sharepoint list i do not want to create new one ,copy paste datasheetview is not working as expected and taking time do we have any options?

Comment: I've built universal solution for this. It can be activated by feature for any list in site collection.<br>
Here is video description (in Russian lang): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pn_jTnM_eUU<br>
Please contact me if you are interested. My e-mail: t602xp@gmail.com, kind regards, Yuriy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in functionality to export excel table to SharePoint List. 
[image]

More information here:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-an-excel-table-to-sharepoint-974544f9-94bc-4aa8-9159-97282d256dab

Update:

For export table to existing SharePoint list, you can use a flow to do the work. 
Here is a sample flow works in my end. You can have a try.
[image]

Comment: But it will create new list can we write in existing one

Comment: @kumar I have add a sample flow. Have a try.

Comment: Thank you i will give a try

Answer (score 0):

make sure the sp format and excel format are the same (fields /columns) in order to do the below:

go to excel, copy paste information

go to Sharepoint list, click List, then quick edit

paste the copied information in the table

Comment: i have done this checks and able to paste data till 20 or 30 rows if i am doing paste more than 500 it does not work i have 51 columns to update

Answer (score 0):

I would create a quick ms flow for this... there is plenty of EXCEL connectors and Sharepoint connectors.. should only take 5 mins... if you need me to write one for you let me know.

Comment: if you can it will be great